# Update text for UIButton from UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in my `UITableViewCell`.  This button launches a `UIActionSheet` so when a user pics a button from the action sheet, I want the text of the button to change to that text.

I show the button with the following code.  I think if I call 'tableView reload' in `actionSheet: clickedButtonAtIndex:` would work but is there a better alternative to just update the `statusButton`?

```
SmokingStatusTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.statusButton.titleLabel.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"smoking_status_display"];


- (IBAction)smokingStatusButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Smoking Status" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"1 Current everday smoker", @"2 Current some day smoker", nil];
    self.smokingStatusActionSheet = actionSheet;
    [self.smokingStatusActionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{    
    if (actionSheet == self.smokingStatusActionSheet){
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:@"daily_smoker" forKey:@"smoking_status"];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:@"nondaily_smoker" forKey:@"smoking_status"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your data source and then you can potentially reconfigure the cell again if required.

If the cell is off screen then it should automatically be updated in your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when it becomes visible again.

If you want to force it to update and it is visible you can:

1. Call `reloadData`
2. Call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`
3. Call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and configure it.

For 2 + 3 you will need to keep a reference to the indexPath of the cell that invoked the action sheet.

If you choose 3 it may help to have your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method set up like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    //..configure label etc here
}
```

By separating out `configureCell:atIndexPath:` you can use the same code to configure the cell.

For example you may call

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{    
    if (actionSheet == self.smokingStatusActionSheet){
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:@"daily_smoker" forKey:@"smoking_status"];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:@"nondaily_smoker" forKey:@"smoking_status"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.selectIndex;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: The code i have is really complex and I would rather not separate the methods at this time.  Is there a way to just update the particular cell that contains the button?  Its `indexPath` is 9.

Comment: As far as I can imagine there should be no difficulty in separating that code as it would just be cut all code after you have retrieved a cell and before you return in and paste it in the new method. But anyway there is no such thing as indexPath 9. An indexPath can have many indexes but for tableview they normally only have two `section` and `row`. I'm going to assume from your "9" that your only have one section, so to get that cell you would need `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0]` be wary of these hard coded magic numbers they will most likely bite you later.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything:`NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0]]; 
        [self.vitalsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

Comment: In the code you gave you are display `smoking_status_display` but updating `smoking_status` is this right? They are two different keys so they have different data

Answer (score 0):

You can call -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on the table, or just get a reference to the cell directly (-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]) and set the button text.

Comment: How do I set for the array though?  The indexPath for the cell which contains the button is 9.  `NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:9]; 
        [self.vitalsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`